How to prove $\mathbb{E}X>0$ implies $\mathbb{P}(X>0)>0$
let X be a non-negative simple random variable, $\{a_k\}_{1\leq k \leq n}\in \mathbb{R}$, $\{A_{k}\}_{1\leq k\leq n}$ be a finite partition of probability space. Here is my proof:
$$let \:X=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k \mathbb{1}_{A_k} 
\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}X=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k \mathbb{P}(A_k)>0 
\Rightarrow \exists i, 1\leq k \leq n \: s.t. a_i\mathbb{P}(A_i)>0 
\\\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\{w\in\Omega:a_i\mathbb{1}_{A_i}(w)>0\})>0
\Rightarrow  \mathbb{P}(\{w\in\Omega:\sum_{1\leq k \leq n} a_i\mathbb{1}_{A_i}(w)>0\})>0
\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X>0)>0$$
I'm not sure if second line of proof is correct. Furthermore, how do I prove if X is a non-negative random variable?

If $X\geq 0$ and $P(X>0) = 0$, then $X=0$, so $E[X] = 0$.
